Does uniform sampling from a sample set preserve its distribution
Given a set of $N$ i.i.d samples $\delta_1, \dots, \delta_N \in \Delta$, where each $\delta_i \sim \mathbb{P}$ is distributed according to some distribution $\mathbb{P}$ over $\Delta$, i.e., $(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_n) \sim \mathbb{P}^N$.
If we select a subset of size $M \leq N$ of the samples uniformly, independently of the samples, and without replacement, i.e., every subset has the same probability $p$ to be selected. Are the resulting selected samples still distributed according to $\mathbb{P}$ (or $\mathbb{P}^M$ for the subset)?

You don't even have to select subsets randomly: you could, for instance, elect always to select the first $M$ of the results.  Clearly that's distributed according to $\mathbb P^M.$ Because the distribution is the same no matter what subset you like, the conclusion follows.

Yes, they are.
The key assumption here is that the subset selection is done independently of the sample. If this would not be the case, then one could think of many cases where this does not hold. For example, if one would choose the $M$ smallest out of $N$ r.v.s, the resulting sample will not be a sample from $\mathbb{P}^M$. This is because you generally do not select values in the upper tail of the distribution but you do select values in the lower tail.
In case of independent sampling, this is not a problem. One could think about this as if one would have just generated $M$ samples without looking at the remaining $N - M$.
We can formalize this mathematically. Let $X^M$ denote the vector of length $M$ you have taken as a subset and let $Y^N$ denote $N$ dimensional vector. Firstly, note that $Y$ is distributed iid, which means that all elements of $Y^M$ have the same distribution for any particular chosen subset $M$ (in fact, this property is also called exchangeability, which is weaker than iid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables).
Then let $\mathcal{Y}$ denote the outcome space of $Y$. By law of total probability we have that
$$
P(X^M = x) = \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}^{N-M}} P(X^M = x, Y^{N-M} = y)
$$
We know that $Y^N = (X^M, Y^{N-M})$ when the first $M$ elements have been chosen as subset. However, we can also have other subsets chosen and still have that $\{X^M = x, Y^{N-M} = y \}$ thus we need to sum over all possible subsets. Let us now denote any chosen subset by $r$ which gives
$$\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}^{N-M}} P(X^M = x, Y^{N-M} = y) = \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}^{N-M}} \sum^{\binom{N}{M}}_{r = 1} P(X^M = x, Y^{N-M} = y | R = r)P(R = r).$$
Note that given $R=r$ and the values in $X^M$ and $Y^{N-M}$, we know the values in $Y^N$. Let $(x_r, y)$ denote this particular outcome (sorry, I know this is sloppy notation but hopefully it illustrates the idea). Furthermore, we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}^{N-M}} &\sum^{\binom{N}{M}}_{r = 1} P(X^M = x, Y^{N-M} = y | R = r)P(R = r) \\
&=\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}^{N-M}} \sum^{\binom{N}{M}}_{r = 1} P(Y^N = (x_r, y)| R = r)P(R = r) \\
&= \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}^{N-M}} \sum^{\binom{N}{M}}_{r = 1} P(Y^N = (x_r, y))P(R = r)
\end{align*}
as the chosen subset is independent of the outcome. Now simply sum the last terms out (probabilities sum to 1 and law of total probability) to obtain the final results
$$
P(X^m = x) = P(Y^m = x).
$$
Note in particular that we did not even need uniform sampling! The results also holds when $P(R = r)$ assigns non-equal probabilities to the different subsets. So all we need is independence of the chosen subset and the particular sample.
Hope this helps!

Thanks a lot for your answer, Stan. That confirms my intuition of just assuming to have sampled less. Do you, by any chance, know about a source I could cite for this, where this situation is addressed?

Probably it's in a textbook somewhere but I'm not sure which one. It should also not be too hard to prove. Let me edit the answer.
